# Introduction to Probability Models, Tenth Edition (Ross) Example 4.7 Questions

Tags: stochastic-processes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXzLs.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSdhL.jpg)

How was the state transition probability matrix obtained for this example question? I hope you can provide help, thank you!

Comment: Your link isn't working.

Comment: The $(i, j)$ entry of the transition matrix is the probability of going from state $i$ to $j$. Look in the $i$th row of the table, and see what number of claims will lead to state $j$. For example, if $(i, j)=(2,3)$ you see from the second row of the table that the only way to reach state 3 from state 2 is by having "1 claim" which has probability $a_1$, and this is the $(2,3)$ entry of the transition matrix.